# Why does this approximation constant work?

Tags: integration, optimization, algorithms, approximation

I found an algorithm that used an approximation of $\log_2(x + 1)$ from $0$ to $1$ which simply followed the line $y = x + k$ where $k$ was some constant they discovered to be something like $0.043$. I wondered where this constant came from, so I made [a Desmos page](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hobesera7t) to experiment, and I graphically figured out what it represents.

[image: The Desmos page]

My idea was that I'd have to take the integral of the absolute value of the difference between the two curves and then minimize the average height with respect to the value $k$. This did not yield the desired $0.043$ that the algorithm used. However, the $0.043$ seems to be the number where the integral is **spread out the most "evenly"** (another way I could see it is that the maximum error is minimized. Notice how the maxima all match up). Is there some sort of statistical or actual algebraic way of expressing this? I'm just a high school student, I'd love to know how to express my findings better. Cheers.

Comment: I think I know the algorithm you are talking about. I remember the value $0.043$ is the one that minimizes the maximum error (i.e., the second quantity in Rob Pratt’s answer), and it seems also to be the case from the picture you are showing. There is a way to compute this quantity analitically if you know some calculus: you can find the maximum value of the function $log_2(1+x)-x$ in the interval $[0,1]$ (computing the derivative of the function and setting it to be zero), then divide the result by $2$ and you should obtain your desired value of $k$

Comment: Using this approach, I get $k=(\log_2(1/\ln(2))-1/\ln(2)+1)/2$, which is approximately $0.04303566…$

Comment: I wonder why that approach works, and where the division by 2 comes from in general

Comment: @LorenzoPompili. Why dividing by $2$ ?

Comment: We know exactly what are the intersection points. $$-\frac{W_{-1}\left(-2^{k-1} \log (2)\right)}{\log (2)}-1\qquad \text{and}\qquad -\frac{W\left(-2^{k-1} \log (2)\right)}{\log (2)}-1$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

Comment: Look at the graph. I divided by two because $k$ is not the maximum error (i.e. the second quantity in RobPratt’s answer), it’s just the vertical shift of the graph of the linear approximation of the logarithm, and you want to choose $k$ so that the maximum error is minimized. For $k=0$, the maximum error is $\log_2(1/\ln(2))-1/\ln(2)+1$ (let me call this number $\alpha$). For $k=\alpha$, the maximum error is also $\alpha$. But choosing $k=\alpha/2$, the error becomes $\alpha/2$ and it’s easy to see from the graph that this is the optimal value of $k$

Comment: I wrote everything down in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain my comments.

Let’s call $\alpha:= \log_2(1/\ln(2))-1/\ln(2)+1$. In this answer, we want to find $k\in\mathbb R$ so that the following quantity is minimized:
$$ \max_{[0,1]} |\log_2(x+1)-(x+k)|=:err(k) $$
(the second quantity in RobPratt’s answer), which I called the maximum error, and which I believe is the quantity that is being minimized in the algorithm mentioned by the OP.

By definition of absolute value, and by some properties of $\max$ and $\min$, we have that
$$ err(k)=\max\left\{\;\max_{[0,1]} \log_2(x+1)-(x+k)\;\;,\;\; \max_{[0,1]} -\left(\log_2(x+1)-(x+k)\right)\;\right\}=$$
$$ =\max\left\{M-k,-m+k\right\}, $$
where $M$ and $m$ are respectively the maximum and minimum values of the function $f(x)=\log_2(x+1)-x$.

Now one can use some Analysis, computing the derivative of the above function and studying its graph (I will skip this as I think it should not be difficult), to conclude that
$$ M=\alpha\qquad\text{and}\qquad m=0. $$
It follows that
$$ err(k)=\max\{\alpha-k,k\}=|k-\alpha/2|+\alpha/2 $$
achieves its minimum value when $k=\alpha/2$, meaning $$err(\alpha/2)=\alpha/2.$$
As I mentioned, this value is approximately $\alpha/2= 0.04303566$, pretty close to the number $0.043$ in the question.

Hence the division by $2$. It’s essentially because of the absolute value. If one looks at the graph I think can figure out why we have to choose $k$ to be half of $err(0)$.

Comment: I believe you've found the exact answer. I meant to say the number was "something like" 0.043. Wonderful explanation, Mr. Pompili. Could you tell me how the algebraic representation of $max\{a, b\}$ can be derived? I haven't seen that before

Comment: Thank you! Sure, you start with the definition of the absolute value: $|x|=\max\{x,-x\}$. Then, $|a/2-b/2|=\max\{a/2-b/2,b/2-a/2\}$. Then you can pull out a constant from the maximum: $|a/2-b/2|=\max\{a,b\}-(a/2+b/2)$, so you finally have $\max\{a,b\}=(a/2+b/2)+|a/2-b/2|$. This works for any $a,b\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: What did you mean when you “pulled out a constant” from the max operator? That piece lost me but the rest is clear

Comment: I mean that $\max\{x+c,y+c\}=\max\{x,y\}+c$, that is, you can pull out the constant $c$ from the maximum.

Answer (score 3):

Your first idea corresponds to finding $k\in\mathbb{R}$ that minimizes
$$\int_0^1 \left|\log_2(x+1)-(x+k)\right| \mathrm{d}x.$$
Your second idea corresponds to finding $k\in\mathbb{R}$ that minimizes
$$\max_{x\in[0,1]} \left|\log_2(x+1)-(x+k)\right|.$$

Comment: Woah, that's pretty interesting. Could you please provide more detail as to how computing the minimization of the second expression yields 0.043? Or is that very complex to do?

Comment: One approach is to find a finite interval for $k$, say $[0,0.1]$, and then use [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @RobPratt's answer, consider the function
$$\Phi(k)=\int_0^1 \left|\log_2(x+1)-(x+k)\right| \,dx$$ which is to very pleasant.

Using numerical integration for a given value of $k$, we can generate the following table
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & \Phi(k)\\
 0.00 & 0.0573050 \\
 0.01 & 0.0479013 \\
 0.02 & 0.0397416 \\
 0.03 & 0.0329156 \\
 0.04 & 0.0275365 \\
 0.05 & 0.0237532 \\
 0.06 & 0.0217750 \\
 0.07 & 0.0219273 \\
 0.08 & 0.0248382 \\
 0.09 & 0.0326950 \\
 0.10 & 0.0426950 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ Zooming or interploating, we should obtain $k_{\text{opt}}=0.0644465$ for which $\Phi=0.0215533$.

There is another possibility which is equivalent to a linear regression based on an infinite number of data points. Minimize
$$\Psi(k)=\int_0^1 \big[\log_2(x+1)-(x+k)\big]^2\,dx$$ $$\Psi(k)=k^2+k \left(\frac{2}{\log
   (2)}-3\right)+\left(\frac{7}{3}+\frac{2}{\log
   ^2(2)}-\frac{9}{\log
   (4)}\right)$$ Differentiating
$$k_{\text{opt}}=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{\log (2)}=0.057305\quad \implies\quad \Psi=\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{\log ^2(2)}-\frac{3}{\log (4)}=0.000659753$$

We could even make a small improvement considering
$$\Psi(a,b)=\int_0^1 \big[\log_2(x+1)-(ax+b)\big]^2\,dx$$
$$\Psi(a,b)=\frac{a^2}{3}+a \left(b-\frac{1}{2 \log (2)}\right)+b^2+2 b
   \left(\frac{1}{\log (2)}-2\right)+\frac{2 (\log (2)-1)^2}{\log
   ^2(2)}$$ Differentiating with respect to $a$ and $b$ gives
$$a=\frac{9}{\log (2)}-12=0.984255\quad \text{and} \quad b=8-\frac{11}{2 \log (2)}=0.0651773$$ giving
$$\Psi=\frac{72 \log (2)-23}{4 \log ^2(2)}-14=0.000639095$$ which is a marginal improvement.

Comment: That's pretty nice, but the second idea is what interests me. The one that yields 0.043, minimizing the maximum as @RobPratt put it

Answer (score 0):

*I prefer to add a separate answer for @RobPratt's second case*

*After @LorenzoPompili's comments*

$$F(x,k)=\left|\log_2(x+1)-(x+k)\right|$$ As I wrote in comments, the intersection points are

$$x_{\text{low}}=-1-\frac{W_{-1}\left(-2^{k-1} \log (2)\right)}{\log (2)}\qquad \text{and}\qquad x_{\text{high}}=-1-\frac{W_0\left(-2^{k-1} \log (2)\right)}{\log (2)}$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function. The solution of $x_{\text{low}}=x_{\text{high}}$ is $$k=1-\frac{1}{\log (2)}+\frac{\log \left(1+\frac{1-\log (2)}{\log
   (2)}\right)}{\log (2)}$$ which is exactly twice the famous number.
$$F\left(\frac{1}{\log (2)}-1,1-\frac{1}{\log (2)}+\frac{\log
   \left(1+\frac{1-\log (2)}{\log (2)}\right)}{\log (2)}\right)=0$$  Why the double ?

Comment: So, $x_{low}$ and $x_{high}$ are the intersections of the two graphs, right? Why are you imposing them to be equal? This does not correspond to the value of $k$ for which $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} F(x,k)$ is minimized.