# best constant $\mu$ for $\log_2(1+x)\approx x+\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, algorithms, approximation

I was recently reading about the fast inverse square root algorithm, and in one step it uses the approximation
$$
\log_2(1+x)\approx x
$$
for $x\in[0,1]$.
this approximation can be made better by adding a constant term $\mu$
$$\log_2(1+x)\approx x+\mu$$
apparently the optimal constant is $\mu \approx0.043$. I am looking for a derivation of this constant. I tried minimizing a few measurements of error myself, however I never got the expected value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4577579/why-does-this-approximation-constant-work/4579143#4579143

Comment: One interesting thing to think about when posing a questing like yours is what exactly is meant by "better" or "best". You could mean "having the smallest possible worst-case error for any x value in $[0,1]$" or "having the smallest error near $x=0.5$ and having tolerable error elsewhere" or you could mean "having the smallest error on average for a random point in $[0,1]$" etc. All of which are perfectly meaningful and useful depending on the application. Unsurprisingly, $\mu$ is dependent on your sense of "best".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we'll compute the best uniform approximation by a constant $\mu$ of
$f(x) := \log_2(1+x) - x$ on $0 \leq x \leq 1$, that is $f(x) \approx \mu$.
The shape of $f$ shows that, for any constant $c$, $f - c$ will have three
extrema, two at the endpoints and one internal. With the approximation
$f \approx \mu$, the error at both endpoints is $-\mu$ and at the (unknown)
internal point $\xi$, $\log_2(1+\xi) - \xi - \mu$.

By the equioscillation theorem, the best approximation has extrema equal in
magnitude but of alternating signs, in this case:
\begin{equation*}
        \log_2(1 + \xi) - \xi - \mu = (-1)(-\mu),
\end{equation*}
thus $\mu = \frac{1}{2}\log_2(1 + \xi) - \frac{1}{2}\xi$.
The internal extremum occurs where the derivative of $f(\xi) - \mu$ vanishes,
and a bit of calculation
shows this is at $\xi = 1/\log 2 - 1$. From this we get $\mu = 0.043035666$.